# PHP search and merge array elements if they have an identical substring

Tags: php, arrays, regex, foreach, preg-match

I have this php array:

```
Array (
     [0] =>
"BLABLABLA   08.09.15

 00.00.00  BBB  BBB  X3 0000  00:00   00:00
 00.00.00  BBB  BBB  TP 0000  00:00
 FNC015P blablablablablabla    blablabla
  1  blablabla     blablabla
 am blablabla blablabla
 blablabla blablabla blablabla
 blablabla
 blablabla
 bblablabla blablabla
 H999999  blablabla
blablabla
blablabla
blablabla
blablabla "


    [1] => 
"00.00.00  BBB  BBB  X3 0000  00:00   00:00
 00.00.00  BBB  BBB  TP 0000  00:00
 FNC015 blablablablablabla    blablabla
   blablablablablabla    blablabla
 blablablablablabla    blablabla
 blablablablablabla    blablabla
 blablablablablabla    
 blablablablablabla    bla
  blablablablablabla    blablabla
 H999996   blablablablablabla    blablabla
 blablablablablabla    bla
 blablablablablabla   
 blablablablablabla    blabla
 blablablablablabla    blablabla
 blablablablablabla    blablabla
 blablablablablabla    blablabla"

    [2] =>
"BLABLABLA   08.09.15
  00.00.00  BBB  BBB  X3 0000  00:00   00:00
 00.00.00  BBB  BBB  TP 0000  00:00
 FNC234  blablablablablabla    blablabla
 blablablablablabla    blablabla
blablablablablabla    blablabla
 blablab
 blablablablablabla    blablablablablablablablabla    blablabla
 blablab
H999999 blablablablablabla    blablabla
blablablablablabla    blablablablablablablablabla    blablabla"

[3] =>
"BLABLABLA   22.09.15
BLABLABLA
 22.09.15  STR  FNC  X3 2810  14:20   17:25
 29.09.15  FNC  STR  X3 2811  18:15
 FNC042  blablablablablabla    blablabla
 blablablablablabla    blablablablablablablablabla    blablabla
blablablablablabla    blablabla
blablab
 H999997  blablablablablabla    blablabla"
)
```

What I want to do is merge into one element the items that have the same H______. Like the folowing for the previous example:

```
 Array (
     [0] =>
"BLABLABLA   08.09.15

 00.00.00  BBB  BBB  X3 0000  00:00   00:00
 00.00.00  BBB  BBB  TP 0000  00:00
 FNC015P blablablablablabla    blablabla
  1  blablabla     blablabla
 am blablabla blablabla
 blablabla blablabla blablabla
 blablabla
 blablabla
 bblablabla blablabla
 H999999  blablabla
blablabla
blablabla
blablabla
blablabla 

+

"BLABLABLA   08.09.15
  00.00.00  BBB  BBB  X3 0000  00:00   00:00
 00.00.00  BBB  BBB  TP 0000  00:00
 FNC234  blablablablablabla    blablabla
 blablablablablabla    blablabla
blablablablablabla    blablabla
 blablab
 blablablablablabla    blablablablablablablablabla    blablabla
 blablab
H999999 blablablablablabla    blablabla
blablablablablabla    blablablablablablablablabla    blablabla"


    [1] => 
"00.00.00  BBB  BBB  X3 0000  00:00   00:00
 00.00.00  BBB  BBB  TP 0000  00:00
 FNC015 blablablablablabla    blablabla
   blablablablablabla    blablabla
 blablablablablabla    blablabla
 blablablablablabla    blablabla
 blablablablablabla    
 blablablablablabla    bla
  blablablablablabla    blablabla
 H999996   blablablablablabla    blablabla
 blablablablablabla    bla
 blablablablablabla   
 blablablablablabla    blabla
 blablablablablabla    blablabla
 blablablablablabla    blablabla
 blablablablablabla    blablabla"


[2] =>
"BLABLABLA   22.09.15
BLABLABLA
 22.09.15  STR  FNC  X3 2810  14:20   17:25
 29.09.15  FNC  STR  X3 2811  18:15
 FNC042  blablablablablabla    blablabla
 blablablablablabla    blablablablablablablablabla    blablabla
blablablablablabla    blablabla
blablab
 H999997  blablablablablabla    blablabla"
)
```

I have to find the item of the array the substring H_____ and compare with other items and if equal merge. I found examples of removing duplicates and finding exactly same item, but this is not the case.
however unfortunately not always I have the same number of spaces, characters before and after the H______

I got the regex for the key: "#H\d+#" and I know that I need to use preg_match.

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See comments in code. The use of `\b` matches at a [word boundary](http://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2pattern.html) and prevents strings like `XXH12345` from being matched.

```
$a = [
    "This is one with H11111",
    "This is one that has an H22222    in it",
    "Tricky one WITH22222 in it",
    "This is another H11111, like the first one",
    "Here's a line without any number at all",
    "Here goes H33333",
    "H22222, finally."
];

foreach ($a as $key => $element) {
    // Find any string matching H<digits> pattern
    if (preg_match('#\bH\d+\b#', $element, $numbers)) {
        $number = $numbers[0]; // Remember first found pattern

        if (!isset($keys[$number])) { // Do we know this from before?
            $keys[$number] = $key; // No, remember the index of this number
        }
        else {
            $a[$keys[$number]] .= " + " . $element; // Yes, append to existing value
            unset($a[$key]); // Then remove the appended element
        }
    }
}
print_r($a);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => This is one with H11111 + This is another H11111, like the first one
    [1] => This is one that has an H22222    in it + H22222, finally.
    [2] => Tricky one WITH22222 in it
    [4] => Here's a line without any number at all
    [5] => Here goes H33333
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I create some algorithm maybe is not perfect but is work.

```
$array = [
    'aaaaa aaa H999997 aaa
    aaaa aaaa',
    'bbbbb bbbb bbbb
    bbb H999997 b',
    'cccccccccc ccccccccccc H999993
    ccccccc cccc'
];

$mergeMap = [];
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (preg_match('/H[0-9]+/', $value, $matches)) {
        $searchId = $matches[0];
        $mergeMap[$searchId][] = $key;
    }
}
$result = [];
foreach ($mergeMap as $key => $indexes) {
    $result[$key] = '';
    foreach ($indexes as $index) {
        $result[$key] .= $array[$index];
    }
}
print_r($result);
```

And output:

```
Array
(
    [H999997] => aaaaa aaa H999997 aaa
            aaaa aaaabbbbb bbbb bbbb
            bbb H999997 b
    [H999993] => cccccccccc ccccccccccc H999993
            ccccccc cccc
)
```

PS. If is any other way (better?), I'll glad to see how this problem can be solved.